# Using cloudinary(attachinary) with rails plus jQuery file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload, cloudinary

I am trying to upload my images on cloudinary using the jquery file upload gem.

I followed this tutorial on doing this using attachinary, but I think either I am missing something or the tutorial is incomplete because after following it, I did get a form with a button to upload multiple images on cloudinary but the jquery file upload UI with progress bars are not getting displayed, I just have a simple button with the choose file as label.

Please help me to understand where have I gone wrong and how to get that ui of jQuery file upload gem with the progress bars.

The tutorial that I followed is
https://github.com/assembler/attachinary

Here are my files

```
/*routes.rb*/
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  root 'prime_petz#home'

  get 'prime_petz/home'

  get 'prime_petz/about'

  get 'prime_petz/contact'

  resources :listings
  mount Attachinary::Engine => "/attachinary"
end
```

/*Listing.rb*/

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attachments :photos, maximum: 10
end
```

/*Application.js*/

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
// Loads all Semantic javascripts
//= require semantic-ui
//= require jquery-fileupload
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require cloudinary/jquery.cloudinary


//= require attachinary
//= require_tree
```

/*new.html.erb*/

```
<%=form_for @listing, :html=> { class:'ui form centered black segment' } do |f|%>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.attachinary_file_field :photos,class:'ui button gallery' %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

/*gemfile*/

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'attachinary'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "jquery-fileupload-rails"
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'semantic-ui-sass', github: 'doabit/semantic-ui-sass', branch: 'v1.0beta'


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

/*listing.js.coffee*/

```
jQuery ->

$('#new_listing').fileupload
dataType:"script"
add: (e, data) ->
data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", data.files[0]))
$('#new_listing').append(data.context)

progress: (e, data) ->
if data.context
    progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
    data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

With this what I am able to view is just a plain ChooseFiles button.

Comment: Hey how did you finally get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you included the following jQuery code in the form view?

```
$('.attachinary-input').attachinary();
```

Comment: Yes I did that too, still no success

Comment: Do you have any jQuery errors in the console (under the browser's 'Developer tools')? Can you share a URL to a live webpage where this is demonstrated?

Comment: If you want I can share my screen with you using team viewer or skype.And regarding any error's on the console,no there aint any of them.

Comment: Please feel free to open a support ticket, and I'll be happy to continue this with you (http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Answer (score 0):

According to the attachinary readme,

> Attachinary jquery plugin is based upon jQuery File Upload plugin but without any fancy UI (it leaves it up to you to decorate it).